Dissolve on model QGIS
I have a problem doing the dissolve on the QGIS model. I have a layer with fid and DN, and I am trying to dissolve both of them. When I do the tool on the project, without the model, it works, but when I do it in the model it doesn't. I have tried everything, but with no results (no nulls, add a column with unique id, etc).
Can you help me?
Update 2/1/2025: I don't get any error message, but when I open the new layer in the project its empty. I add a screenshot of my attribute table below. The weird thing is that without the model the tool works fine.


Same for me, gave up and use buffer by 0 with dissolve instead.

What do you mean by "it doesnt work"? Do you get errors? Can add a screenshot showing a part of the attribute table so it is possible to reproduce your data?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please provide the exact QGIS version used and Operative System and the model execution log and any error message displayed in the Log Messages panel.
